# Android ListView can't click Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView. I implemented OnItemClickListener to open a ContextMenu when an item is clicked.

```
lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            showMenu(view);
        }
    });
```

And the code to create menu.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_menu, menu);
}

public void showMenu(View v) {
    registerForContextMenu(v);
    openContextMenu(v);
}
```

My problem is, when I clicked on one item of ListView, it does open the Menu. But if I go back to the ListView, I can't click that item again. The same for other items, it can't be click after close the menu. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's the `openContextMenu(v);` here?

Comment: @SpK: to open the menu when item clicked.

Comment: I think  registerForContextMenu(listView);

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set that up incorrectly.  You register for context menu when you set the adapter, not in a button click.

It should look like this:

```
setListAdapter(lists);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Then you have your `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected` methods (I create mine programatically, but your inflated one woudl work just as well):

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("List Operations");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit List");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete List");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit List") {
      //  Do your edit stuff here
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete List") {
      // Do your delete stuff here
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

You don't need to use `onItemClick` unless you want to do something on a short press of the item (context menu is long press).

Comment: No what I want is when I click on the item (short click), it open the menu. I insert registerForContextMenu(getListView()); into my code, but when I click the item, it didn't open menu or anything

Comment: Ok I solved it. In onItemClick, I just need to add openContextMenu(getListView()), then it will open menu on short click. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code will works.

code:

```
  ListView listview=(ListView)findViewByid(R.id.listview);

   /**** here write appending data to listview*******/
     ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,/**your list items**/);
     listview.setadapter(adp);
     registerForContextMenu(listview);

   //listview item click listener
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int p, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected" + p, 30).show();
}});

   /****do your context menu code here*******/
```

Comment: What is adp in listview.setadapter(adp);